# Can TDateTime be used in a DLL for other languages to use?

Tags: delphi, datetime, dll, compatibility

The `TDateTime` in Delphi is represented as a `Double` type. I need to export this in a DLL to be used in other languages (such as C#, C++, Java...). Is the `TDateTime` (represented as a `Double` in Delphi) compatible with other languages? (Do they recognize Double types as a date/time?) Or do I need to convert it to a string when exporting and convert it on each end?

Comment: SysUtils.DateTimeToSystemTime should help: "This procedure is primarily used to convert TDateTime values for making a Windows API call."

Comment: You can interpret a double as the days since the delphi epoch in any other language. You just have to code it in each language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Languages other than Delphi will accept a `Double` as a floating point value, but will not understand that it's intended to represent a date or time value. A `TDateTime` is simply a means that Delphi uses to refer to a point in time; it's compatible with COM-based dates in the sense that it is used to refer to a point in time that has an origin of `12/30/1899 00:00:00` (the equivalent of a TDateTime variable initialized to `0`).

If you want other languages to understand it as a date value, you'll need to either convert it to a string or document it as being a reference from that point in time and expect the other language to use it appropriately.

Comment: Something like a Julian date might also come in handy instead of using strings as it's pretty standard across all languages.

Comment: After re-evaluating what I was asking, and the comments, I realized the real question should have been "How should I export a 'TDateTime' to other languages from a DLL?"

Comment: Don't.  Export something more portable instead.  A string in a standard format.  Or a `SYSTEMTIME`, like Abelisto suggested.